# How to create a caller/callee graph?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I want to display a 'flow' chart of a process showing time spent in children relative to the parent. For example, say that I have MethodA which calls MethodB and MethodC. 30% of the time relative to MethodA in MethodB and 70% in MethodC. I want to display something like this:
[image]

I know this is a sort of vague question, so to narrow the scope, I don't know what kind of chart this might be. What kind of Libraries might provide the capability to display this type of chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `Graph#` for same purpose - but this is a WPF library. Good news for you is that it uses 
`QuickGraph` (http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) library internally and you can google around that library to see whether there is any code for it to be used as part of winforms.